# Set a dynamic environment variable (%cd%) as Icon Path for files or shortcuts in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, icons, relative-path, shortcut

How to set the Icon path of a file or shortcut to a path containing a dynamic environment variable, in particular the current directory %cd%.

The problem is to set a custom (non-system) icon for a file and that icon remains used on other computers. Both the file and the icon would be shipped in a .zip. When the .zip is uncompressed on other computers, the file should be displayed with the custom icon.

I'm stuck because Windows needs an absolute path and this path changes when the .zip is uncompressed on another computer (with a different absolute location).

I've tried, without success, through the GUI Properties window or with PowerShell scripts like

```
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$lnk = $wshshell.CreateShortcut("c:\TheFolder\ASubFolder\nameOfMyShortcut.lnk")
$lnk.TargetPath = "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start \"\" \"Includes\myApplication.exe\""

$lnk.IconLocation = "%cd%\Includes\myApplication.ico"
#$lnk.IconLocation = ".\Includes\myApplication.ico"

$lnk.Save()
```

You can that there's a trick to make the TargetPath unsensitive to the absolute location of the package folder.

The question is about the how to set the IconLocation path variable relative, both tentatives doesn't work:

```
$lnk.IconLocation = ".\Includes\myApplication.ico"
```

or

```
$lnk.IconLocation = "%cd%\Includes\myApplication.ico"
```

As I understand, the environment variable %cd% is dynamical, Windows does not like it.

Comment: `%CD%` wouldn't be useful even if it worked, because you don't know what the current directory of the application showing your icon is going to be. (You seem to think that `%CD%` is the directory containing the shortcut.)

Comment: Right! So, %cd% is dead; how to specify a relative path for the icon location?

Comment: Shortcuts do not support relative paths for icon locations. You should just put the desired icon in myApplication.exe and it will be picked up automatically.

Comment: But I want to minimize the number of files in the folder: only the application launcher and the folder containing libraries and resources files. I don't want to make people confused about lot of files in the folder.

Comment: Not sure what your point is. Wishing something were true doesn't make it true. Shortcuts don't support the feature you desire. You'll have to come up with some other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the problem was solved is the following: Create launcher with C# (or a static binary) that do not requires shipping dll in the root folder of the package. The launcher starts the dynamic binary .exe that is located in the resource folder.